# Iterating and Printing content of a HashMap with nested array in a jsp

Tags: java, javascript, arrays, jsp, hashmap

I have a HashMap created in the following manner,

```
HashMap products = new HashMap<String, String[]>();
products.put("001",new String[] {"SAM", "100"});
```

Now I need to print the content of the Map in a table, I know how to print it, if it is created with out the nested array, as shown in the code snippet below.

```
<%
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : orderList.entrySet()) {
%>
<tr>
    <td><%=counter++%></td>
    <td><%=entry.getKey()%></td>
    <td><%=entry.getValue()%></td>
</tr>
```

How can I print the content in the HashMap with the nested Array?

Solution I tried,

```
<%
                for (Map.Entry<String, String[]> entry : Order.entrySet()) {
            %>
            <tr>
                <td><%=counter++%></td>
                <td><%=entry.getKey()%></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <%
```

Comment: Have you tried using `Map.Entry<String, String[]> entry : orderList.entrySet()`?

Comment: If you combine my code above and @StanislavL's code below you should have your solution. If that's not the case you need to post what is going wrong. Is it not printing? Is it giving an error?

Answer (score 1):

You need one more nested loop

```
for (String arrayElement: entry.getValue()) {
 <%=arrayElement%>
```

You can define a nested table in the `<TD>` instead of the simple `<td><%=entry.getValue()%></td>`

Comment: In that case What is the method to define the first loop? I tried Map.Entry<String, String[]> entry : orderList.entrySet(); and it didn't work

Comment: You define products map but you some unknow orderList. What' the orderList? You said "it didn't work". In which way it didn't work? Any errors? results?

Comment: Hi, Its Just a typo, The solution I tried is added to the original question.

Answer (score 1):

Why cant we use jstl here? Like..

```
<c:forEach var="entry" items="${products}">
  Key: <c:out value="${entry.key}"/>
  Value: <c:forEach var="arrayVar" items="${entry.value}">
            <li>${arrayVar}</li>
        </c:forEach> 
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: @Luiggi.. No. Here I'm iterating through that array and printing the result. So it'll print the value. If we give like `<c:out value="${entry.value}"/>` then it'll print like you mentioned.

Comment: Oh right. Didn't see the inner `<c:forEach>`. Then this is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to get the solution thanks to StanislavL and Shaded answers so the complete solution is illustrated below,

The HashMap is defined as following,

```
static HashMap<String,String[]> products = new HashMap<String, String[]>();
products.put("001",new String[] {"Samsung", "USD. 500 ", "5 Units" });
```

This Hashmap can be printed in a table as illustrated below using a JSP.

```
<% int counter = 1; %>
<table class="styledLeft" id="moduleTable">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th width="10%">No</th>
                    <th width="10%">Model No</th>
                    <th width="30%">Model/Make</th>
                    <th width="30%">Price</th>
                    <th width="20%">Available Quantity</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <%
                    for (Map.Entry<String, String[]> entry : orders.entrySet()) {
                %>
                <tr>
                    <td><%=counter++%></td>
                    <td><%=entry.getKey()%></td>
                    <%for (String arrayElement: entry.getValue()) {%>
                    <td><%=arrayElement%></td>
                    <%
                    }
                    %>
                </tr>
                <%
                    }
                %>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

The Final output will look like this,

[image: The Final OutPut]